# how to minus 1 week from a date and get back a custom date format

Tags: date, vbscript

so I have a date in this format 20-Nov-2012 and what i would like to do is minus one week from this and get back 13-Nov-2012
I have tried this:`DateAdd("ww", -1, DatePart("d", Date) & "-" & MonthName(DatePart("m", Date), 1) & "-" & DatePart("yyyy", Date) )`

but i get the wrong date format back :13/12/2012
any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Formatting the date going into the DateAdd function will likely not impact the output.  Try something like:

```
weekEarlier=DateAdd("ww", -1, Date)
document.write(DatePart("d", weekEarlier) & "-" & MonthName(DatePart("m", weekEarlier), 1) & "-" & DatePart("yyyy", weekEarlier))
```